# kubectl get service --all-namespace filter out by if Ready matches Available

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Looking for query/filter to list only certain deployments: if AVAILABLE column matches READY

Example:

```
NAMESPACE NAME READY UP-TO-DATE AVAILABLE
app1      app1 1/1    1          1
app2      app2 2/2    2          2
app3      app3 0/0    0          0
```

Basically just to see anything that is actually running app1 and app2 should be showing from a query.

Comment: which version of kubectl you using ? mine did not show `READY` state. for `services`

Comment: I get that if I run:  ```kubectl get deployment --all-namespaces```
kubectl version: v1.19.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a generic answer for all kind of resources that prints the `READY` state in the format of Integer/Integer.

```
kubectl get deployment --all-namespaces |grep -P '\s+([1-9]+[\d]*)\/\1\s+'
```

This is only using `grep` to capture the matching (integer)/(same-integer) format.